# jQuery AJAX does not detect success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code.

```
$(".likeBack").on("click", function(){
  var user = $(this).attr("user");
  var theLikeBack = $(this).closest(".name-area").find(".theLikeBack");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "processes/rewind-knock.php",
    data: "user="+user+"&type=likeback",
    success: function(json){
      alert("SUCCESS");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      alert("XHR: " + jqXHR + " | Text Status: " + textStatus + " | Error Thrown: " + errorThrown);
    }
  });
});
```

Here, everything is functional. Network tab shows request and response well received as required. However, the `success` part is not getting executed. I tried adding `beforeSend` and `complete` and both are getting executed but `success` part (nothing inside the `success` blog is getting executed). I don't understand the reason why.

**UPDATE**

Add error part. It returns:

```
XHR: [object Object] | Text Status: parsererror | Error Thrown: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

**UPDATE 2**

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: There's also an [`error`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) "event". Read the documentation and use all of its parameters to find the problem.

Comment: _"Network tab shows request and response well received as required."_ - And the console? Any errors (CORS, parsing, ...)?

Comment: I tried that too. Exception shows nothing. Blank.

Comment: No errors in console.\

Comment: _"Type: `Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`"_ - What exception? And there are **three** parameters. If `success` is not executed then `error` will be executed and then `textStatus` and/or `errorThrown` will have information about the underlying problem.

Comment: @Andreas updated the question with error part and response. Please check.

Comment: You are POSTing json data with `type:"POST"` and `dataType:"json"`, but the error seems to say that it actually did not receive JSON.

Comment: @Kokodoko Network tab shows it does.

Comment: @Kokodoko added screenshot. Please check.

Comment: The response is not just JSON. Check the _raw_ response or change the `dataType` to `text` and log the raw value.

Comment: @Andreas thanks. I think I have caught the error now. Going to give it a try.

Comment: And don't use `alert()` for anything other than annoying the user of your site. `console.log()` is the tool you should be using instead.

Comment: @Andreas `alert()` was only used for debug here. Don't worry. I am not a naive developer. I know it's the worst thing a developer can provide to it's LIVE users. For debugging I prefer `alert()` instead of `console.log` more because I don't need to open console everytime and clear a bunch of errors and warnings and finding my thing in between them. With alert I can go full screen. Individual Dev choices you know! It's removed as soon as the task is done!

Comment: `alert()` only understands strings and blocks the execution/gui. `console.log()` is superior in all cases. It does not block the execution, can handle any type possible, has structured output and many more features.

Comment: @Andreas yes I have experienced that many times. There are times when I need to switch to `console.log` for the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

give data in ajax like this and check,

data : {'user':user,'type':'likeback'},

In your Php code when you return the data, place all data in a array then use this,
echo json_encode($arr); //return the array in json form

now in your success function use
console.log(JSON.parse(json));

hope may help you. Thank you

Comment: Sorry bro. Already solved. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: May I know what was the issue?

Comment: I was trying to fetch date from table with no records in it.

Comment: Ohh ok, nice that you found the loop hole ✌️✌️

Comment: hmm.. and for the type of answer you gave, please use comments. Comments are used for discussions. Answer only if you know the exact solution.

Comment: Sure i will keep this in mind. Thank you